# How to create a query for displaying the lessons from the current category(course) LearnDash customization?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to customize the course content list forming by the LearnDash plugin. Now on the lesson page in the sidebar displays just a boring list of the lessons included in the course (the current shortcode formed it). But I need to display the list of the lessons with thumbnails and other meta information from the lessons. For this purpose, I try to use this chunk of code:

```
             <?php
                $args = array(
                    'cat' => 153,
                    'post_type' => 'sfwd-courses',
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'publish');
                query_posts($args);
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="timeline">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                        <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

And I always see the same answer: "No Posts Sorry". Please help to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code which helps you to display lessons fo specific category.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sfwd-lessons',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ld_lesson_category', //double check your taxonomy name in you db 
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => 26,
        ),
       ),
    );
$q = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<div class="timeline"> <?php
    if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); ?>    
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I've got a little clarification: I can't get it what is 'field'    => 'id'? What parameter should I insert there?

Comment: Hi, use 'field' =>'id' if you want to display lessons by category id and 'field' => 'slug' for display by category slug. 
if you use 'field' => 'id' then use 'term' => 26 //category id.
if you use 'field' => 'slug' then use 'term' => 'category-slug'